# How to preselect a select box choice based on the value of a choice?

Tags: javascript

I have the following select box.

```
I have the following select box
 <select name="model_number"  class="iump-form-select "   ><option value="ZL111" >ZL111</option><option value="ZL222" >ZL222</option><option value="ZL333" >ZL333</option><option value="ZL444" >ZL444</option><option value="ZL555" >ZL555</option></select>
```

before entering this page I am setting a cookie with the value for the model number, eg "ZL222"

```
 var M111 = getCookie("ModelNumber");
```

when this page loads I would like the appropriate model number already selected based on the value of the input cookie.

I want the select box to "auto change" to the value read from the cookie.  I can read the cookie just fine, but I don't know how to set the select box to the correct choice.  For example, if the cookie is ZL222 when the page finishes loading i want the select box to show ZL222 as the SELECTED value.

```
<option value="ZL222" >ZL222</option>
```

However, I am stuck on how to do the above.

I tried this based on other examples I saw, but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('model_number').getElementsByTagName('option')[M111].selected = 'selected';
```

I want to be able to preselect the value based on the incoming cookie value, in this case, which is set to a variable called M111.

Comment: `document.getElementById('model_number').value = getCookie("ModelNumber");`

Comment: I need to SELECT that option value so that the select box shows that particular choice as the currently selected one.  Your statement will set it to that value, but it doesn't change the drop down choice to that item.

Comment: So it selects the value, if you have other code related than you need to fire that. I can only go with what you provided.... You said you want to select the option which is what the code does, seems like there are other steps you did not explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate doing unorthodox things but here goes anyway...

```
var M=document.TheForm.model_number;

var E=M.getElementsByTagName('option');

for(var i=0; i<E.length; i++){

 if(E[i].value==M111){M.selectedIndex=i; break;}

}
```

PS: Change the form name to what you've got.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Select the input, set the value, fire the change event

```
const sel = document.getElementById('model_number')
sel.value = getCookie("ModelNumber");
sel.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

Comment: It doesn't have an Id

Comment: This looks more promising-- there isn't an ID associated with this select box, just a name.  Can this be changed to work with the select box name instead of ID?  Is anything needed to do the "dispatchEvent"?

Comment: So use a querySelector with a name selector.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getElementById() because your selection menu doesn't have an ID but a NAME!

If this selection menu is not a part of a form to necessitate a NAME then change that to ID like this...

```
<select id="model_number">
```

And then to set the selected index use this method...

```
model_number.selectedIndex=3;  // or whatever number
```

If it's part of a FORM and thus want to preserve the NAME, you can access it like this:

Given...

```
<form name="TheForm">
```

Then...

```
document.TheForm.model_number.selectedIndex=3;
```

Alternatively you can also access it like this:

```
document.TheForm.elements['model_number'].selectedIndex=3;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Follow-up:  Isn't "selectedIndex" the number in the list of choices, eg, 4th item?  I need to be able to select the choice based on a text value that comes into the page via cookie, and is assigned a variable.  if the variable is "ZL222" and I do ...selectedIndex=3 how is that selecting the choice based on the value of the Option item?   NOTE:  I can't add an "ID".. I have to access the form by name.

Comment: You should stick to numeric values not strings. The string is the label displayed like “Toyota” to the user, but the selected value=”3” should be a number, so too in that cookie, not a string. Every OPTION in that menu has a value attribute which should be a number.

Comment: UNfortunately I have to have a string as the value... not my choice.